# PHP: Category and Subcategory through echoing variables

Tags: php

I am only able to echo the first selectbox but not the sub category. I checked the code for syntax errors and there were none found. I am guessing the logic is incorrect. Can anyone tell me  Why is it not displaying the subcategories select box ?

```
   <?php 

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);

    if(isset($_GET["category"]) && is_numeric($_GET["category"]))
    {
        $category = $_GET["category"];
    }


    ?>


    <form name="theForm" method="get">

        <!-- Category SELECTION -->

   <select name="category" size="6" onChange="autoSubmit();">
                <?php
        $categories = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY c_id');

        while ($row = $categories->fetch()) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['c_id'] . '"';
        if ($row['c_id'] == $category) echo ' selected';
        echo '>' . htmlentities($row['category']);
      }
                ?>
   </select>

        <br><br>



    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is most likely returning 0 results due to your use of a variable inside of a string using single quotes.

```
$subcategories = $dbh->query('SELECT s_id, subcategory FROM subcategory Where c_id = $category');
```

Use double quotes around your query, or concatenate the value like `'... c_id = ' . $category`

But even better than that, learn how to use parameterized queries and bind the values instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do You have two DB tables? One for categories and one for subcategories? And what when a subcategory would have another subcategory/ies? Would You then create another table `subsubcategory`???

Better approach is to have just one table `categories` with columns `id`, `parent`, `title`, etc., where if main category the `parent` column contains `0`, when subcategory the `parent` column contains the ID of the parent category. Even better would be when implementing traversal tree or similar method.

I don't see a mistake in Your code but probably `$_GET["subcategory"]` contains no value or no numeric value thus `$subcategory` is not set...

Did You tried debugging?

Comment: The problem was with the single quote not being double. Although after reading your comment: You are completely correct. Because I am planning to implent 1 main category with 3 subcategories. If you are so kind  and show me a short written out example of doing it that way. Thank you

Comment: @jonthecoder2346 I won't give You a code but You can find a lot about the topic on google: https://www.google.com/#q=php+category+tree.